# Cypress:Is there any way to check invisibility of an element

Tags: cypress

In our application when user do some actions that require communicatiion with server -a loading bar will be displayed on top panel.Once the action completed-Loading bar will be disappeared.In tests we are using this as a check before we move to next step.
In selenium i am checking the disappearance of loading bar as shown below

```
WebDriverLongWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id("loading-bar")));
```

Is there a similar way to check invisibility of an element in Cypress

instead of waiting for loading bar i am waiting for the request to finish

```
as shown below cy.server()
            cy.route('POST','**/saveExpression').as('saveExpression')
            cy.get('.IEE-save-button',{ timeout: 100000 }).contains('Apply Expression').click();

            cy.wait('@saveExpression').then((xhr)=>

            {
                cy.contains('browse',{timeout: 60000}).click()
            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, it's ideal to use `.should('not.be.visible')`. To place in your example as below,

```
cy.get('#loading-bar').should('not.be.visible')
```

Since loading bar indicator is dependent on some network request, you can wait for the XHR request to finish before making an assertion. You could use the [`wait()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html) function of cypress. For instance:

```
// Wait for the route aliased as 'getAccount' to respond
cy.server()
cy.route('/accounts/*').as('getAccount')
cy.visit('/accounts/123')
cy.wait('@getAccount').then((xhr) => {
  cy.get('#loading-bar').should('not.be.visible')
})
```

Comment: Thanks , seems working , instead of looking for progress bar i am just waiting for network request