# How to make sure page loads completely in cypress

Tags: user-interface, cypress

I am working in cypress.
Steps to repro

I just visit the login page by cy.visit()-spinner is loading
passed the credentials using type-spinner is still loading
click on submit.-spinner is  still loading
 its throwing error .. why because the login page XHR calls didnt get completed thats why still we can see spinner loading in top and i tried to click the submit button before it gets loaded,may be because of poor network-telling invalid credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to wait for the XHR request to get completed and validate the page load or perform other actions.

Here is a sample,

```
// Wait for the route aliased as 'getAccount' to respond
cy.server()
cy.route('/accounts/*').as('getAccount')
cy.visit('/accounts/123')
cy.wait('@getAccount').then((xhr) => {
  cy.get('#loading-bar').should('not.be.visible')
})
```

Here is a similar solution which I have previously given - [Cypress:Is there any way to check invisibility of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112455/cypressis-there-any-way-to-check-invisibility-of-an-element/55126240#55126240)

Comment: waiting for xhr request to complete is always a better option, you can further add validations on response of the XHR request. This way if the xhr returns 4xx or other errors we should expect the loading-bar to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You check if the button is present and then click on the button.If

```
describe('check if button present', function () {
    it('check for button using CSS Selector', function () {
      cy.visit(url)
      let found = false
      let count=0
      while (!found) {

        const nonExistent = Cypress.$('.btn-selector')

        if (!nonExistent.length) {
          found = false
          count=count+1
          cy.wait(1000)
          if(count==60)
          {
            found = true
            cy.log('Element not found after 60 seconds..Exit from loop!!!')
          }
        } 
        else 
        {
          found = true
          cy.get('.btn-selector').click()
        }

      }

    })
  })
```

Comment: @kajai Kundu
this actually checks for the button visibility? from my side button is always visible and once cypress type for both email and itin no and click on submit ,there happen the issue ,still the login page XHR calls are going on..  need something to make sure all XHR calls are done and its fine to click submit button

Comment: @midhunk : is it possible to share url in public?