# Cypress never reaches step 2 after visit() - stuck in nuxt-loading

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, cypress

the cypress visit function waits for the load event from the page - and that is fired, so cypress goes on with the next step in the test. this of course fails because nuxt is still in the loading state (see link below). and it never gets resolved, even if i keep waiting after the test fails (in the electron browser).

everything works fine if i have another visit call beneath the first one. but thats not really a solution. is anyone else having a similiar problem or had this before?

here a example testrun: https://i.imgur.com/2nHt7RW

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "kinda fires the load event"?

I guess the similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374195/how-to-make-sure-page-loads-completely-in-cypress).
Also, if not done that yet, try to add `timeout` option to `visit()` as well.

```js
// Wait 30 seconds for page 'load' event
cy.visit('/YOUR_PAGE', { timeout: 30000 })
```

I'm not sure if any of this helps but I can't comment yet, so had to post this as an answer.

Comment: the timeout only waits longer for the page to send the load event. and that is firing normally. but as i wrote it is stuck in the nuxt-loading (loading.html). and it never resolves.